# Quartiles in a legitimate pdf function

Tags: probability, statistics

I want to ckeck if I am correct in how to calculate quartiles (Q1, Q2, Q3) in a pdf graph function and ask one question.  I am working on a function 
$(3/16)*(x+2)^2$ on $ [-4,0]$

I know that the second quartile is the Median and the correct integral has form 
$$\int_{-4}^{M} \frac3{16}(x+2)^2dx =\frac 12$$
And from that M is calculated. However, what would be the values of the integral be for Q1 and Q3 and why?

Thank you

Comment: you are leaving out the normalization factor of 3/16

Answer (score 1):

If $x_p$ is the $p^{th}$ percentile then

$$ \frac 3{16}\int_{-4}^{x_p}(x+2)^2dx = \frac p{100} $$

Answer (score 0):

Median (same as Q2) means that $P(X \leq x) = 1/2$.

Similarly, Q1 means that $P(X \leq x) = 1/4$ and Q3 means $P(X \leq x) = 3/4$

Therefore, Q1 = a where $$\int_{-4}^{a} \frac3{16}(x+2)^2dx =\frac 14$$

And, Q3 = b where $$\int_{-4}^{b} \frac3{16}(x+2)^2dx =\frac 34$$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, i thought so but did not know why are these values used. Now I can solve my exam correctly =)